# NodeMCU says Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to upload a code to the NodeMCU to Ask FirebaseDatabase for the Sensor State i.e whether Sensor is 1 or 0 which I will change according to my need. Then read the data from the sensor and update on Firebase.

Currently I am Using 2 Sensors i.e MPU6050 and MAX30100. My code is something like this:

```
#include <MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h>
#include<FirebaseESP8266.h>
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<Wire.h>

/////////////////////Define Pins Here///////////////
const int MPU6050pin=D0;
const int MAX30100pin=D3;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define FIREBASE_HOST "//my host"                          // database URL 
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "//my auth"                  // secret key
#define WIFI_SSID "//my ssd"                                                  //Wifi Name
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "//my  wifi password"          //Wifi Password
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////Define Sensors Here//////////////
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////Define Variables Here/////////////
float AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
FirebaseData firebaseData;
int MPU6050state,MAX30100state;
boolean MPU6050flag,MAX30100flag;
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
int MAX30100firstTime=0;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID,WIFI_PASSWORD);                                             //Connecting to Wifi Network
Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST,FIREBASE_AUTH);
//////////////////Set Up Pins Here///////////////
pinMode(MPU6050pin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(MAX30100pin,OUTPUT);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////Initialize all Sensors to OFF///////
digitalWrite(MPU6050pin,LOW);
digitalWrite(MAX30100pin,LOW);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}
void UploadMPUToFirebase(){
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/RoomTemperature",(Tmp/340.00)+36.53);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Acceleration/0",AcX/16384);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Acceleration/1",AcY/16384);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Acceleration/2",AcZ/16384);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Gyro/0",GyX/131);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Gyro/1",GyY/131);
Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData,"/Readings/MPU6050/Gyro/2",GyZ/131);
}
void UploadMAXtoFirebase(){

}
void MPU6050Data(){
Wire.begin();
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
Wire.endTransmission(true);
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
Wire.endTransmission(false);
Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
}
void MAX30100DataSetup(){
  Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");
  if (!pox.begin()) {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }
     pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
 
    // Register a callback for the beat detection
    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
    MAX30100firstTime=1;
    MAX30100DataLoop();
}
void MAX30100DataLoop(){
   pox.update();
    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
        Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
        Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
        Serial.println("%");
 
        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
void TurnSensorsOnOff(){
  if(MPU6050flag){
    digitalWrite(MPU6050pin,HIGH);
    MPU6050Data();
    UploadMPUToFirebase();
  }else{
    digitalWrite(MPU6050pin,LOW);
  }
  if(MAX30100flag){
    digitalWrite(MAX30100pin,HIGH);
    if(MAX30100firstTime==0){
    MAX30100DataSetup();
    }else{
    MAX30100DataLoop();
    }
    UploadMAXtoFirebase();
  }else{
    digitalWrite(MAX30100pin,LOW);
    MAX30100firstTime=0;
  }
  
}
void loop() {
if(Firebase.get(firebaseData, "/SensorState/switchGesture/switchGestureState"))
  {
    if(firebaseData.dataType() == "int"){
      MPU6050state=firebaseData.intData();
      Serial.println("MPU6050 = ");
      Serial.print(MPU6050state);
    }else{
      Serial.println("MPU state is Not Retrieved");
      MPU6050state=0;
    }
    if(MPU6050state==0){
        MPU6050flag=false;
    }else{
        MPU6050flag=true;
      }
  }
  
if(Firebase.get(firebaseData, "/SensorState/switchOxygenHeartBeat/switchOxygenHeartBeatState"))
  {
    if(firebaseData.dataType() == "int"){
      MAX30100state=firebaseData.intData();
      Serial.println("MAX30100 = ");
      Serial.print(MAX30100state);
    }else{
      Serial.println("MAX state is Not Retrieved");
      MAX30100state=0;
    }
    if(MAX30100state==0){
        MAX30100flag=false;
    }else{
      MAX30100flag=true;
      }
  }
/////////////////////////////////Add otherSensorStateCheakingHere  
TurnSensorsOnOff();
}
```

When I try to upload this code to NodeMCU it compiles successfully but gives this error while uploading

```
Executable segment sizes:


IROM   : 451380          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 28276   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1344  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 1936  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 27184 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 482936 bytes (46%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 30464 bytes (37%) of dynamic memory, leaving 51456 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM8
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 2c:f4:32:20:7d:8e
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 487088 bytes to 354774...

Writing at 0x00000000... (4 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (9 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (13 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (18 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (22 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (27 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (31 %)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prashang\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.1/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2938, in main
    operation_func(esp, args)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2374, in write_flash
    esp.flash_defl_block(block, seq, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * ratio * 2)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 104, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 672, in flash_defl_block
    self.ESP_FLASH_DEFL_DATA, struct.pack('<IIII', len(data), seq, 0, 0) + data, self.checksum(data), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 369, in check_command
    val, data = self.command(op, data, chk, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 347, in command
    p = self.read()
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 292, in read
    return next(self._slip_reader)
  File "C:/Users/Prashang/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2045, in slip_reader
    raise FatalError("Timed out waiting for packet %s" % waiting_for)
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Although I found some similar issues so I tried some things to solve this problem:

1. Removed all the pins while uploading the code
2. Tried pressing Reset and Flash button and then releasing the Reset Button by holding Flash button till it uploads
3. Changing Board Versions from latest till 2.5.0

Node of the above solutions worked.

Adding: The basic examples provided with libraries is uploading and working perfectly that means there is no problem with hardware.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You release the Flash button prematurely, Press it "until" the upload is completed.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for replying.I have already mentioned that i tried this flash method and have pressed that until i get this error.But it didnt work.Although i observed a way to deal with it that is if i start getting this error,i leave nodeMCU unplugged for around  10-12 hours and then for sometime(around 4-5 hours,i can upload the code without any error).but this is only a temporary way to deal with this problem.Is there a permanent solution?